# Unstable backup size, where to look for causes

Tags: backup, sql-server-2014

I've got a new **SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000)** instance with about 50 databases, it was recently upgraded from SQL Server 2005.

They were using a lot of backup space so the old maintenance plan was replaced to a different approach:

**Check Db Integrity** -> **Back up Database (Full) (with Compression)** -> **Rebuild Index** -> **Maintenance Cleanup**

That happens everyday while databases aren't being used and it preserves backups for 5 days.

At the beginning it worked OK and a lot of backup drive was saved but then some of the databases started backing up with erratic file sizes.

A few images that display the file size change:

This one went down a whole lot, that was expected. Thing is, it then when down another two times (?)

[image]

This other one when down a bit and then further down in size and finally got bigger than the first time it backed up with compression.

[image]

Finally this one went down in size, further down next day and then up the that place it was the first day.

[image]

---

In this case:

[image]

On restoring, the file the size increases quite a bit:

[image]

So they do restore the way they're supposed to but I'm here wondering, how come they vary in size, I can totally understand the change after the compression but after (?).

Why would the backup behave in this way? Any known reasons?

Additionally: Nothing really going on in the logs.

Comment: If you aren't expecting much to happen on the DB, why rebuild indexes daily? Are you rebuilding all indexes? That is effectively 100% data change on a daily basis (in regard to re-writing the same data every day).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using backup compression, the size of the backup will vary quite a lot assuming data is being changed in the database.

Performing index maintenance each night will move data around inside the database *a lot*, resulting in unpredictable changes to the amount of allocated pages inside the database.  Index defragmentation is not perfect and does not guarantee the index is completely defragmented - it is merely a way of *reducing* fragmentation.

The amount of change you're seeing is nothing to be concerned about, especially when you see your file sizes are measured in *kilobytes*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this was me, I think I'd first rule out `REBUILD` consolidating data into significantly fewer active pages (since `BACKUP` only backs up active pages)

I think I'd restore a 'large' backup to a test server and run the following query to identify used_pages per object.  Save that information off for comparison to the restore of a 'smaller' backup

```
SELECT  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(s.object_id) schema_name,
        OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id) table_name,
        SUM(s.used_page_count) used_pages,
        SUM(s.reserved_page_count) reserved_pages
FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
JOIN    sys.tables t
        ON s.object_id = t.object_id
GROUP BY s.object_id
ORDER BY schema_name,
        table_name;
```

This may not tell you anything new, but it's where I'd start.